# Accessing Angular Scope In Html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to access my angular scope and I keep getting the common issue :"$digest already in progress". I can't use $timeout because I have to be able to do this in the  section of my html because I am using Kendo UI Grid and I have to initialize the grid in the html script section(I wish I could figure out how to do it all in my controller).

The code is pretty simple, so I don't know what else to try.

```
 ....
$(document).ready(function () {


    var scope = $('[ng-controller="NewIncidentController"]').scope();
    scope.$apply(function () {
        scope.submitfailure = true;          
    });
```

});

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of `scope.$apply(function () {scope.submitfailure = true;});`. Have you simply tried  `scope.submitfailure = true;  `?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `scope.$applyAsync().`

Comment: @KishorSubedi not true, it provides enough info to pinpoint a problem. Although answer could be more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

`scope.$apply` would call `$digest` internally which would cause the error you met since **Angular allows only one cycle of digest at a time**. `$timeout` service can execute your function in the next cycle of digest.
For your situation, you can use `scope.$evalAsync`, which will execute the specified function **in the on-going digest process**, thus avoiding the exception.